# How to run Jenkins job with different parameters for many runs?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, dsl

I need to execute `primary-job` Jenkin's job with different parameters.

For this purpose, I created separate job `execute-job` with [Build flow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin).

and **DSL** script with Groovy looks like:

```
// #1 - Build cluster
ignore(FAILURE) {
    b = build("primary-job",
            "KILL_CLUSTER": "true",
            "BUILD_CLUSTER": "true",

            "CALLS_RATE": "50",
            "MAX_SIMULT_CALLS": "400",
            "LOCAL_CODEC": "PCMU",
            "REMOTE_CODEC": "PCMU",
            "NUM_LOOPS": "4",
            "VOICE_TRACE": "0",
            "MAX_LOSS_PERCENT": "1",
            "NUM_RUNS": "3",

            "RECORD": "true",
            "NUM_CHANNELS": "1"
    )
}
// #2
ignore(FAILURE) {
    b = build("primary-job",
            "BUILD_CLUSTER": "false",

            "CALLS_RATE": "50",
            "MAX_SIMULT_CALLS": "400",
            "LOCAL_CODEC": "PCMU",
            "REMOTE_CODEC": "PCMU",
            "NUM_LOOPS": "4",
            "VOICE_TRACE": "0",
            "MAX_LOSS_PERCENT": "1",
            "NUM_RUNS": "3",

            "RECORD": "true",
            "NUM_CHANNELS": "2"
    )
}
.....
```

Abowe you can see only 2 runs.

However, I need to make such job triggering **~320** times.

Even if one job failed we have to run next one.

I believe I can't to type manually to DSL script so long build execution list. It is too long.

I can't find any solution for this task.

***How to call one Jenkins job from another with different parameter so many times?***

Answer (score 1):

The script is written in Groovy, so you should be able to use that to script it.

```
[ "job1", "job2", "job3" ].each { jobname ->
   ignore(FAILURE) {
      b = build( jobname)
   }
}
```

Comment: good solution. You are running sequentially 3 different jobs. However, I need to run the same one. And passing parameters to it should be changed for every next run.

Comment: Also,  for just running jobs, without any next usage you can omit declaration and use `build(jobname)` instead of `b = build(jobname)`.

Comment: The above was just an illustration. I take 3 parameters in and use them in a loop. Study some Groovy, and you should be able to find out what you need.